# Data from controller do not appear in templateUrl in AngularJS version 1.6.10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routeparams

I am making a shop only to learn Angular, but I have problem and I coulnd find the solution anywhere. The site is located locally on my PC. I am not using even the localhost for now.

I have file **application.js** to set the routes of my site:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module( 'app' , ['ngRoute','controllers'] );

app.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider',function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/products', {
    controller: 'products',
    templateUrl: 'partials/products.html'
  });
  $routeProvider.when( '/product/:id' , {
        controller: 'product',
        templateUrl : 'partials/product.html'
    });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
}]);
```

Here is my file with controllers:

```
'use strict';

var controllers = angular.module('controllers',['ngRoute']);

// display all products
controllers.controller('products',['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http){
  // $scope.displayProducts = function(){
    //load data from file
    $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'model/products.json'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // display the data
      $scope.products = response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.products = 'Error downloading data...';
    });
  // };
}]);

// edit single product
controllers.controller('product',[ '$scope' , '$http' , '$routeParams' ,function($scope, $http, $routeParams){

    //load data from file
      $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'model/products.json'
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // display selected data
        $scope.product = response.data[$routeParams.id];
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          $scope.product = 'Error downloading data...';
      });
}]);
```

I want the second controller to open the **product.html** and the user would be able to edit the product. Inside the **product.html** there is only `{{product}}`. It all worked when I was using **Angular in version 1.3.15**, but when I have changed it to **Angular version 1.6.10** the `{{product}}` displays me nothing. Why is that ? There is no error in the console for this.

Comment: Are you sure that `$routeParams` has values? What is the `response` value? Are you sure `response.data[$routeParams.id]` finds actual data?

Comment: Yes I am sure, when I am using angular 1.3.15 everything works well. When I change it to 1.6.10 is displays me nothing. The way I attach the files:
    `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Have you added any debug statements? If you `console.log(response.data)` what do you get? What about if you `console.log(response.data[$routeParams.id])`? What about `console.log($routeParams)`?

Comment: In Angular 1.3.15
`console.log(response.data)` are two Objects(my products)
`console.log(response.data[$routeParams.id])` is my object with passed id in url
`console.log($routeParams)` is object with field (`id: 0`) it is also my product

In Angular 1.6.10 I have empty console...

Comment: If you have an empty console, that would imply your `$http` call is not finishing and you are never hitting the success or error functions. I would look into this (potentially the url).

Comment: https://github.com/kendyl93/ngShop - here are the files